# How many non-isomorphic graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

How many non-isomorphic graphs are there in the sequence

s: 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6

What is a good approach to tackle this problem, especially if something similar to it was on an exam?

Comment: What does a graph being in a sequence mean?

Comment: I presume that's the degree sequence - as in 6-regular graphs on 10 vertices?

Comment: @gilleain yes that's it

Comment: Well, using GENREG, you can show that there are 21 such graphs, but how you do that without generating them I've no idea http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html

Comment: Oh, if you want to just enumerate them rather than list them, there are bounds : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there